# how to truncate and add a read more in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

hey guys i have this piece of code

```
 <%#=link_to raw page.body%></a></div>
 <div class='col-md-8'>
      <div  class="container">
        <h4><b>   <%= link_to page.title, page_path(page.id)%> </b></h4> 
        <p><%=link_to raw page.body%></p> 
    </div>
    </div>
 <% end %>
```

i want to truncate the page.body output so after 200 text, it'll truncate it and add a read more button to view the full page.
How do i do it please

Comment: If you are truncating HTML (as seen by the use of `raw`) then you will probably have leaking tags, you probably should use HTML truncator: https://github.com/nono/HTML-Truncator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ActionView::Helper::TextHelper#truncate](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) might work for that:

```
<%= link_to truncate(page.body, length: 200) { link_to 'Read More', '#' } %>
```

The block passed permits you pass an additional link_to helper which you can make work with JS or any other as you need.